# why target="blank" doesn't open a new window

Tags: window, new-operator

I am going to show $Content in a new window. after some searches I found the following code. but it doesn't open a new window and echoes $content in the same page.

```
 <form method="POST" action=" <?php echo $Content; ?> " target="blank"></form>
```

update:
THIS IS THE CODE:

```
    <?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
{

include 'library/config.php';
include 'library/opendb.php'; 
$Unit_Code    = $_POST['Unit_Code'];
$File_Name    = $_POST['File_Name'];
$_SESSION['Unit'] =$Unit_Code;
$_SESSION['file'] =$File_Name;
$query = "SELECT Unit_Code,File_Name, type,size, Content FROM Units WHERE ((Unit_Code = '$Unit_Code')&&(File_Name='$File_Name'))";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
list($Unit_Code, $File_Name, $type, $size,  $Content) = mysql_fetch_array($result);
header("Content-length: $size");
header("Content-type: $type");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$File_Name");
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="dblclick.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<form method="POST" action=" <?php echo $Content; ?> " target="_blank"></form>

</body>
</html>

<?php 
include 'library/closedb.php'; 
exit;
}

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's `target="_blank"`. The underscore is important.

Comment: but, still it doesn't open a new window.

Answer (score 1):

You missed the _

```php
<form action="URL TO POST THE FORM" method="POST" target="_blank">
  <?php echo $Content; ?>
</form>
```

Comment: but, still it doesn't open a new window. I don't have any thing else in this form. I just want a new window to be opened and $content be displayed in it.

Comment: is the `$Content` is the content of the form or the URL you want the form to post information ?

Comment: it is the content of an html file which is retrieved from a database.

Comment: can you show us what is it ? You might have to move the `<?php echo $Content ?>` inside the `<form>` tag.

Comment: what do you mean inside the <form> tag? it is already there. I will add my whole code as an UPDATE to this post.

Comment: sorry. but I don't know what to write instead of "URL TO POST THE FORM". there is no url. everything is in $content. sorry if It seems stupid!!!

Comment: can you show us what is the content on the $Content variable? You don't need to replace "URL TO POST THE FORM" if everything is done on the same page.

Comment: it can be anything. it is actually some lectures notes in MSWord that is saved in html format. I don't create $content.

Answer (score 0):

Missing: `_` before `target`in your HTML attribute: `< .. target="_blank">`

Comment: but, still it doesn't open a new window.